# Images in cache not getting used

Tags: php, ajax, image, caching, manifest

I'm working on this web app for which I'd like to cache some static content to lower loading times on a slow connection. Other parts are being generated through PHP and AJAX and can therefor not be cached.

I'm successfully using the cache.manifest to cache the static content, such as images, but I notice that the dynamic pages aren't using them. Instead they are downloading the images again, even though they have been cached, making the caching useless.

Because my dynamic content is generated based on GET-requests the dynamic pages are in the NETWORK section of the manifest (e.g. "user?*"). Might that have something to do with it? Is there a way to maybe force using cached images?

Note: the exact full reference to the dynamic pages (e.g. "user?id=22") is of course not in the manifest. Does that make the cache unreachable for those pages?

Comment: Do you send `Cache-Control`, `Pragma` and `Expires` headers for the static content? How do you implement the static content? Will they be served directly by the webserver?

Comment: I'm not using any of those headers at the moment. Reading up on them now. Regarding the second question; the images are stored on the server and I generate references to them in PHP.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Looked into those header but don't really see how they can help me. Do you suggest caching all pages and then adding those headers to the pages containing dynamic content? What I'm basically asking is if pages not explicitly referenced (because of dynamic parameters) in the 'NETWORK' section of the cache.manifest can use the cached resources.

Comment: This would suggest not; http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1946-non-cached-pages-cannot-access-resources-cached-in-the-cache-manifest.htm

Comment: You need to add those headers to the content which you want to get cached. Also you need to support the If-Modified-Since Header and reply with HTTP 200 or HTTP 304.

Comment: Afraid I don't understand. Looked into those, don't really see an influence. The caching works fine, it's just that the non-cached pages (most of the application) aren't using the cached content. Any good reference or tutorial of what you're suggesting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I've come up with my own solution.

Since caching dynamic pages (e.g. "user.php?id=22") broke my application I tried inserting an iframe containing a reference to the manifest instead of referencing it on the page itself. That did not seem to do it for me.

I now include an explicit reference with a wildcard to the dynamic pages in the CACHE section of the manifest. That does seem to work. They are now **not** getting cached entirely with parameters et al. (so the application remains functional) but are using the cached images. Might not be ideal but seems to be a pretty simple solution.

I have not yet tried removing those iframes but my guess is that they can be removed.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
./user.php
./user.php?*
etc...
NETWORK:
./db_connect.php
etc...
```